# Pandas iterrows won't iterate through dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a need to iterate through the dataframe with a bunch of strings, integers values and JSON objects.

Via the code provided I want to iterate through such dataframe, collect needed values from JSON objects and write them as column values to a new dataframe.

However the code below returns only the first row of a desired dataframe and the next one contains only test_id from the first row and NaN. What do I do wrong?

Sorry for bad posting.

```
def create_clean_data(df):


    columns = ['test_id','winner_id', 'original_id', 'block_id', 'w_views','w_clicks', 'w_recirculation', 'w_time', 'o_views', 'o_clicks', 'o_recirculation', 'o_time']
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

    for row in df.iterrows():
        parsedData = row[1]


        try:
            winner = json.loads(parsedData.winner)
        except ValueError:
            winner = []

        try:
            params_on_finish = json.loads(parsedData.params_on_finish)
        except ValueError:
            params_on_finish = []

        test_id = parsedData.id
        if 'block_id' not in winner:
            continue

        block_id = winner['block_id']
        winner_id = winner['headline_id']
        test_id = parsedData.id
        original_id = parsedData.variants[2:15]
        w_views = 0
        for param in params_on_finish:
            if param['headline_id'] == winner['headline_id']:
                w_views = param['views']
                w_clicks = param['clicks']
                w_recirculation = param ['recirculation']
                w_time = param ['time']
            if param['headline_id'] == parsedData.variants[2:15]:
                o_views = param['views']
                o_clicks = param['clicks']
                o_recirculation = param ['recirculation']
                o_time = param ['time']
        data2 = pd.DataFrame([[test_id, winner_id, original_id, block_id, w_views, w_clicks, w_recirculation, w_time, o_views, o_clicks, o_recirculation, o_time]], columns = columns)
        d22 = data2.append({'test_id': test_id}, ignore_index=True)

    return d22
```

Comment: You need to declare and initialize `d22` outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: did you mean for `data = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)` to really be `d22 = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)`?

Comment: @CilantroDitrek beat me to it by 12 seconds! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to apply a function to each source JSON. This function
should return a *Series*, so the application result will be just a *DataFrame*.

I created the test *DataFrame* the following way:

```
dd = [
  [ "n1", """{
    "id": "id1",
    "winner" : { "block_id" : "b1", "headline_id" : "x1" },
    "params_on_finish" : [
        { "headline_id" : "x1", "views": "v1", "clicks" : "c1",
          "recirculation" : "r1", "time" : "t1" },
        { "headline_id" : "x2", "views": "v2", "clicks" : "c2",
          "recirculation" : "r2", "time" : "t2" } ],
    "variants": "aax2" }""" ],
  [ "n2", """{
    "id": "id2",
    "winner" : { "block_id" : "b2", "headline_id" : "x3" },
    "params_on_finish" : [
        { "headline_id" : "x3", "views": "v3", "clicks" : "c3",
          "recirculation" : "r3", "time" : "t3" },
        { "headline_id" : "x4", "views": "v4", "clicks" : "c4",
          "recirculation" : "r4", "time" : "t4" } ],
    "variants": "aax4" }""" ]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dd, columns=['id', 'txt'])
```

Then we need a function to be applied to each "source JSON" - the content
of `txt` column:

```
def fn(src):
    try:
        parsedData = json.loads(src)
    except ValueError:
        parsedData = {}
    test_id = parsedData['id']
    winner = parsedData['winner']
    winner_id = winner['headline_id']
    original_id = parsedData['variants'][2:15]
    block_id = winner['block_id']
    w_views = w_clicks = w_recirc = w_time = ''
    o_views = o_clicks = o_recirc = o_time = ''
    params = parsedData['params_on_finish']
    for param in params:
        if param['headline_id'] == winner_id:
            w_views = param['views']
            w_clicks = param['clicks']
            w_recirc = param ['recirculation']
            w_time = param ['time']
        if param['headline_id'] == original_id:
            o_views = param['views']
            o_clicks = param['clicks']
            o_recirc = param ['recirculation']
            o_time = param ['time']
    return pd.Series([test_id, winner_id, original_id, block_id,
        w_views, w_clicks, w_recirc, w_time,
        o_views, o_clicks, o_recirc, o_time ])
```

Note that the only need to call `json.loads` is to read the source string.
After that the function operates on elements of the returned JSON object.

And the actual processing involves 2 steps:

- Create a DataFrame - a result of application of the above function
  to `txt` column of `df` (for now column names are consecutive numbers).
- Set target column names.

So the code is:

```
df2 = df.txt.apply(fn)
df2.columns = ['test_id', 'winner_id', 'original_id', 'block_id',
    'w_views', 'w_clicks', 'w_recirc', 'w_time',
    'o_views', 'o_clicks', 'o_recirc', 'o_time']
```

I shortened some column names to fit the result on the screen, but
you may change them back to your original names.

For demonstration purpose I created each column as a string, but if you have
other requirements, change the type of respective columns as you need.